# How do I pass I->getType() as an argument to CreateCall in llvm?

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-clang

I need to pass the datatType from llvm to an external Cpp program.
I find the type in LLVM using:

`Type *elementType=I->getType();`

`Call=IRB.CreateCall(funcName,{arguments});`

How do I pass elementType as an argument? Also, what data type should be used in the external cpp program to receive this argument?

Comment: Your question is really "I need to pass an instance of a complicated data type to an external program, how do I do that and how do I receive it in the other program", which is *much* too general to answer. Sorry.

Comment: Have you considered passing the typeString instead and then interpreting the string in the external Cpp program??

Comment: Yes, I passed the type as String and was able to retrieve it in my CPP program.

Answer (score 0):

To create a `call` instruction, you don't pass types, you pass values (a list of `Value*`).

Comment: How do I convert the Type I get to Value? I essentially need to pass the data type of a variable like int, float, etc to the cpp program.

Comment: You can't convert a type to a value. As well as you can't pass types to functions in C++. Functions are supplied with values, not types. Or are you talking about C++ templates?